# Piping variables from shell script to Python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have a script called "script.sh," whose contents are:

```
#!/bin/sh
export A=5
```

I want to execute this script from *within* python (iPython actually) and read the variable 'A'.

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.call('./script.sh')
A=os.environ['A']
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, giving me an error that A cannot be found. If I understand correctly, subprocess is actually running in a different shell than the one that os.environ queries. But then why can't I run something like:

```
subprocess.call('echo $A')
```

?

What should I change to make this work? In general, I just want to obtain the value of "A" from the script, preferably by executing the script through some form of shell (the actual script is quite long).

For some more info, the script will contain *login credentials*, so ideally I'd like a safe,minimalist way of accessing their values.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to make this work. A subshell can't set environment variables in its parent.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Right, I've just added an edit. Is there a way I could access it from the subprocess shell? That's the part I don't get

Comment: Yes, you're successfully setting the environment variable in the shell spawned by `subprocess.call`, which then disappears right after your script runs.

Comment: The subprocess is using a different instance of the shell each time.

Comment: `os.environ` is captured the first time the `os` is imported. Even if it wasn't the subprocess, it wouldn't work. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ

Comment: @kindall: Is there a way I can immediately return the values of the subprocess call? I only care about obtaining the value of A, and have no need of actually setting A in the enviornment shell.

Comment: Maybe you simply want to access stdout instead? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call

Comment: Your "A" not an variable ! `$` ?

Comment: I also believe [Execute bash script that defines environment variables using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500328/execute-bash-script-that-defines-environment-variables-using-python) to be pertinent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I'm not entirely sure I understand how the marked-duplicate question answers this one. Would I run:

subprocess.Popen(['. "$1"; shift; exec "$@"', "_", "./script.sh",
    "echo", "$A"], shell=True)

(that doesn't seem to work)

Comment: @AlexR., you're looking at the wrong section -- adopting parts that are for when `script.sh` is something that *uses* the variable itself, as opposed to transporting its value back to the parent. The answer *does* distinguish between its various sections, and which is useful in which circumstance.

Comment: @AlexR., ...what you want here is emitting a NUL-delimited stream from the subprocess and parsing it in the parent, which is what... well, really, everything but the top 1/4 of the linked question's accepted answer discusses.

Comment: Take a look at `subprocess.Popen(['set -a; . "$1"; cat /proc/self/environ', "_", "./script.sh", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\0')`; you'll see that `A=5` is among the members of that list. The linked answer also covers practices that'll work where `/proc/self/environ` (being a Linuxism) isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to source the script in the subshell (so it sets the variable in the same shell process), then echo the variable in that subshell:

```
a = subprocess.check_output('source ./script.sh; echo "$A"', shell=True)
```

Then you can read from the pipe to get the value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not an expert at this but from what I understand, shell=true and stdout=PIPE is discouraged in the answers I've seen. Specifically, if my script contains credentials, is this still a good solution?

Comment: I changed it from `subprocess.call` to `subprocess.check_output`. Is that still discourged? If so, you should use `Popen()` and `communicate`.

Comment: I don't see how credentials in the script are relevant to this.

Comment: If it contains credentials, you shouldn't be `export`ing them at all unless you're sure your OS protects environment variables from being read out of process metadata (modern systems do, a great many old ones don't).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought he meant there were credentials elsewhere in the script, not that the value of `A` is credentials, but you're probably right.

Answer (score 0):

The trick will be to spawn a new shell and tell it to both interpret your script's code, and can print out its environment in a way that Python can read it. A one-liner:

```
In [10]: subprocess.check_output(["bash", "-c", "source ./script.sh; env"])
Out[10]: '...\nA=5\n...'
```

What's happening: In general, environment variables are set at the beginning of a program, and any subprocesses can't modify their parent's environment; it's a sort of sandbox. But `source` is a bash builtin where bash says "instead of spawning script.sh as a new (sub-)subprocess which couldn't modify my environ, run the lines of code as myself (bash) and modify my environ accordingly for future commands". And `env` is tacked on so that bash prints the environment separated by newlines. `check_output` simply grabs that output and brings it back into Python.

(As a side note, that `source` command is what you use to update a shell to use a certain virtualenv: `source my_project/bin/activate`. Then the $PATH and other variables of your current shell are updated to use the virtualenv python and libraries for the rest of that session. You can't just say `my_project/bin/activate` since it would set them in a subshell, doing nothing :))

Comment: Environment variables can contain literal newlines. This thus isn't a safe way of representing and parsing them.

Comment: (Consider if an attacker were able to set an environment variable, say via CGI's automatic header->variable mechanism, with a value akin to that created by `CGI_X_evil=$'hello\nLD_PRELOAD=/tmp/exploit.so'` -- if code parsing the output of `env` saw `LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/exploit.so` and then updated your Python program's environment with that, future programs that your Python tool invoked would be running arbitrary code).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Generally, a good point. OP was only trying to update their Python program's environment as a means to an end; as they explained, all they want to do is read the environment created by the script, and get it as a string in Python. Nobody's talking about using that output as the environment for any future program, or the current program; just extracting trusted environment variables.